# Const char to Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm having a problem with a function to generate all sub sequences of a Word. Problem is:

```
cout << *(s + y) ;
```

This line print's a char and i want to add this "char" to a array

Like:

```
char str[100];
str+=(cout << *(s + y) );
```

I know this is wrong but there is any way to do this? To add char by char into a array? (this type `*(s + y)`  is also very weard, compiler is displaying a lot of problems)

Function:

```
void encontra(const char *s)
{
    string str;
    while(*s)
    {
        int x=0;
        while(*(s + x))
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <= x; y++)
                cout << *(s + y) ;
            cout << "\n";
            x++;
        }
        s++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you didn't know before, `*(s + y)` is equivalent to `s[y]` for *any* `y`.

Comment: I want the result of *(s + y), not just *s

Comment: @Pablodias: So use `*(s + y)` (or, equivalently, `s[y]`). That's the character you want. But you'll want `std::string`, not a nasty array, for `+=` to work.

Comment: By the way, your question is inconsistent, do you have an array or a `std::string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the expression

```
str+=(cout << *(s + y) )
```

The first is that the output operator `<<` returns a reference to the stream.

The second problem is that you can't append to arrays like that.

Instead use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), then you can easily append characters to the string:

```
std::string str;
std::cout << s[y];
str += s[y];
```